# How to prove this probabilistic inequality?

Tags: probability, inequality

How to prove this inequality?

Let $m \ge 2$ and $X$ be a random variable that satisfies $\mathbb{P}[X \ge \epsilon] \le e^{-2 m \epsilon^2}$.

Then $\mathbb{E}[e^{2 (m - 1) X^2}] \le m$.

Comment: If $X$ is identically $0$ then your inequality is satisfied for all $m$ but the expectation you desire equals $1$.

Comment: You're right. I revised my question for $m \ge 2$.

Comment: It may be useful to recall that for a nonnegative r.v. $X$, $E[X]=\int_0^\infty P[X \geq x] dx$. I think one can use the given bound and monotonicity to get a straightforward estimate on $P[e^{2(m-1)X^2} \geq x]$ (it is just $P[X \geq f^{-1}(x)]$ where $f(x)=e^{2(m-1)x^2}$).

Comment: First, I think so too. But it did not work as follows.

Comment: If all your estimates along the way were tight then that means the result simply doesn't hold (since everything I just said is exact).

Comment: $E[e^{2(m-1)X^2}] = \int_0^\infty P[e^{2(m-1)X^2} \ge x] dx = \int_0^\infty P[X \ge \frac{\log x}{2(m-1)}] dx \le \int_0^\infty e^{-2m \frac{\log x}{2(m-1)}} dx = \int_0^\infty x^{- \frac{m}{m-1}} dx$. This last integral is equal to $\infty$. It is not worth.

Comment: @HideakiImamura Did you forget that $\int_0^1 P[e^{2(m-1)X^2} \geq x] dx = 1$, so the domain of integration is bounded away from zero? Thus you get some nontrivial bound as soon as $m>2$. (This step was actually necessary anyway: in the derivation you did you took a nonsensical square root in the range $x \in [0,1)$).

Comment: You're completely correct !!! I was wrong. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @HideakiImamura Sorry I made an error in my inequalities; you need $m/(m-1)>1$ which is merely $m>1$. This inequality is essential as was pointed out by lulu.

Comment: @HideakiImamura I turned these comments into an answer. If it is suitable, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if $Y$ is a nonnegative r.v. then $E[Y]=\int_0^\infty P[Y \geq y] dy$. Applying this to $Y=e^{2(m-1)X^2}$ you get

\begin{align}E[Y] & =\int_0^\infty P[Y \geq y] dy \\
& = \int_0^1 1 dy + \int_1^\infty P[Y \geq y] dy \\
& \leq 1 + \int_1^\infty x^{-m/(m-1)} dx \\
& = 1 + m-1 \\
& =m
\end{align} using the given bound with the assumption $m>1$. The statement is also trivially true for $m=1$, but in that case you need to replace $\int_1^\infty P[Y \geq y] dy$ with $0$ without using the given bound.